# If $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R_+}$ is concave and strictly increasing, must there be an $A \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $df/dx|_{x=A}<\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is concave and strictly increasing. Must there be an $A \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $df/dx|_{x=A}<\epsilon$  for some small $\epsilon$?

---

This seems likely, since if $f$ is strictly increasing and concave, the value of the derivative is decreasing in $x$, so there will be some large $A$ for which the derivative becomes arbitrarily small.

---

If the above is true, how general is it? For instance, for the function $f(x,y)$ that is concave in $x$, is it true that $\exists A$ $\forall y$ $(df(x,y)/dx|_{x=A}<\epsilon)$ for some large value $A$?

Comment: I am not sure a function as you described exists. If $f$ is strictly increasing and concave, it is impossible to have $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)\ge 0$. Maybe the codomain of $\mathbb R_{+}$ is misspecified?

Comment: Yes, you're right, the codomain is simply $\mathbb{R}$. Sorry

Comment: Then the claim is not true. You can consider linear functions.

Comment: Even if you mean "strictly concave" function, this is not true, because $f'$ can asymptotically equal some strictly positive number.

Comment: For example, consider $f(x)=x-e^{-x}$, where $f$ is strictly concave and strictly increasing, but $f'(x)\to 1$ as $x\to+\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(If the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$:)
$f(x) = x$ is concave, strictly increasing, but $f'(x) = 1$ for every $x$.

(If the codomain is $\mathbb{R}^+$:)
Such a function does not exist.